# Devise not create session when i logged in at firs time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I have some problems with Devise and user's sessions on my site.

I have admin panel where i can create new users manually. In **Admin::UsersController#create**, before **@user.save** i use **@user.skip_confirmation!** method. After save new User successfully created.

Then I try to log in and i get error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create 
undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class
```

Here is trace log http://pastie.org/3818223

This error rises only when I try log in with newest user's login at first time, in next time with this login everything works fine.

I use
devise v 1.5.3
devise-russian 1.5.0
mongoid 2.4.1
ree 1.8.7
rails 3.1.1

Please, help me. Thanks! :)

p.s. Sorry for my terrible English

UPD: Problem was solved. In my application controller I override method **after_sign_in_path_for** and in this controller I created record in Redis about current_user successfully logged in. I called my function after returning path definition, I still don't understand why it call exception, but when I placed my method befor path definition everything started to work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved. In my application controller I override method after_sign_in_path_for and in this controller I created record in Redis about current_user successfully logged in. I called my function after returning path definition, I still don't understand why it call exception, but when I placed my method befor path definition everything started to work correctly. Thanks.